# What do we mean by writing multiple responder flows in cordapp?

Tags: corda

What is literally happening in multiple responder flow?Are we communicating with multiple nodes?Can we do use multiple responder flow for some other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this, you (the initiator) is applying for a loan; you go to 5 different banks (i.e. 5 responders). Every bank has their own criteria to approve your loan application (one bank requires you to own a house as a guarantee, another requires you to have an annual salary higher than 100,000, and so on).

So even though all responding nodes **can** use the `responder` flow that was supplied by the organization that wrote the `initiating` flow; they are not obliged too, actually it is the responsibility of the responding node to write its own version of the `responder` flow to implement its own business rules.

If the received transaction passes those business rules, the responder approves it (i.e. it signs the transaction); otherwise it rejects it (i.e. throws a `FlowException`).

Comment: Thanks fo the reply.I am new to this.So if we have 5 responder then that means we have 5 separate piece of code each with annotation @InitiatedBy or one piece of code which can handle these five banks?

Comment: If all 5 responders have the same validation rules; then you can have one responder flow; if they validate the transaction differently, then you'll have 5 different pieces of code. Read [this series](https://lankydan.dev/responder-flow-validation) by Dan Newton (R3 engineer); it has 3 articles (read all of them).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to the overriding of responder flows. It allows developers to configure a node to respond using an overridden responder flow rather than the base responder.

You could find more details here:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/flow-overriding.html

Answer (score 1):

As the previous comments say, you can choose to create multiple responder flows or having a single one that implements different logics depending on the information stored in the responding node. There are multiple example in the source code of Corda, if you look for flow handlers, like this one below ([on github](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/bf10299e01deeb627d5f438e8059054f3aaa4b77/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/internal/flows/finality/ObserverAwareFinalityFlowHandler.kt)) where you can see that different logics apply depending on the role of the responding node (set by the InitiatingFlow, in this case):

```
class ObserverAwareFinalityFlowHandler(val otherSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val role = otherSession.receive<TransactionRole>().unwrap { it }
        val statesToRecord = when (role) {
            TransactionRole.PARTICIPANT -> StatesToRecord.ONLY_RELEVANT
            TransactionRole.OBSERVER -> StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE
        }
        // If states are issued to self, then ReceiveFinalityFlow does not need to be invoked.
        if (!serviceHub.myInfo.isLegalIdentity(otherSession.counterparty)) {
            subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherSideSession = otherSession, statesToRecord = statesToRecord))
        }
    }
}
```